# what he did from time 4:06 to 4:08 in this time laps

Tags: modeling

I'm watching this time-lapse and wondering what he did from 4:06 to 4:08.
This is the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2iI6YhEbveQ

Comment: it looks like Alt left click to select the edge loop, then Ctrl B to bevel?

Comment: Why don’t you ask him in the comments?

Comment: He selected the loop of edges but had to do it in 3 goes because he couldn't select the whole loop in one go. Then as @moonboots says he bevelled it. Slow the video down to .25 in Settings and you can see what's going on.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

He Bevelled the edges <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>B</kbd>. To confirm, just slow down Youtube video speed to 0.25 and look at bottom left in video where you will see *Bevel* command activated too

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It's my first question and I'm really amazed with the support of community.

Answer (score 2):

He selected the edges and made a *Bevel*, not *Inset* as I initially thought.

Comment: Thank you. I will fix the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help man.